# Why does root path in my controller maps to index.html in spring boot web application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm testing a controller for a Spring Boot application. I want to map a resource to a path, which should be a part of my API.
My controller is pretty specific about path:

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController
{
  @RequestMapping("${web-interface}")
  public String main()
  {
    return "index.html";
  }
}
```

Here 'web-interface' is a property, as specified in application.yml file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/search-engine
    username: landsreyk
    password: 12345678
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
web-interface: /admin
```

**Expected behavior:**

path: localhost:8080/admin maps to index.html resource

root path: localhost:8080/ maps to nothing, i.e. 404 error.

**Actual behavior:**

path: '/admin' maps to index.html

path: '/' also maps to index.html

*But why? Shouldn't I just see "Whitelabel Error Page". There is no controller, which maps root path to index.html file. It doesn't make any sense.*

By the way, here is my project structure.

[image]

**Solution:**

Rename index.html to any other name, like main.html and root path '/' will no longer map to that resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root path **"/"** by defaults maps to index.html. It is standard for all languages and frameworks. **index.html** is meant to be entry point for your application

Answer (score 2):

It is the default behavior for every entry point. The `DefaultController` implements the default behavior, that's why it doesn't matter if you call **"/"** or **"/root"**.
For further info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.1/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.welcome-page